# How can I obtain a list / cross-comparison table of function / closed-class words in the world's languages? (preferably in softcopy, online etc.)

Tags: comparative-linguistics, translation, words

How can I obtain a list / cross-comparison table of function / closed-class words in the world's languages? (preferably in softcopy, online etc.)

I am looking for something like:

```
                     English.     Chinese.     Malay.   Thai.   Japanese
First-person pronoun  I            wo           saya.    ...     ...
Second-person pronoun ...          ...
```

Looking at perhaps an API, an online database, even the data that translation software like Google Translate use if it does.

Comment: I'm not convinced that what you're asking for is well enough defined to be practical I suppose there may be a core of function words which map onto many other languages, but quite a lot don't - certainly not 1-1.

Comment: Go to Wiktionary, search for the word you're looking for in English (that has the most resources), and look for the "Translation" section.

Comment: Look up Swadesh Lists, of which there are many variants.

Comment: Why would a dictionary appear insufficient?

Comment: @vectory I dun think I have seen a dictionary that has dealt with more than 3 languages, and which present the information in the way i need it (in a table). The key here is *presentation*.

Comment: *presentation* is also the key for a good question. Following Mr Fine's comment, are pronouns really closed class or does that term only apply within one language? Many languages have a dual pronoun, differentiate exclusive and inclusive *we*, or have various different forms depending on register. Your example so far implies that either your primary column will be paraphrased and many other columns empty, or that you are only interested in translations of English "closed-class words" (a concept that I find doubtful). Besides the lexicographics, how is your database programming?